# Get multiple values from XML (Classic ASP)

Tags: asp-classic, xml-parsing

I have a XML file containing a lot of data and i would like to get some of the values for further processing in classic ASP.

My XML file looks like this;

```
<result>
<items>
    <client>
        <clientid>12345</clientid>
        <name>Acme Inc</name>
        <site>
            <siteid>98765</siteid>
            <name>Acme Site</name>
            <workstations>
                <workstation>
                    <id>12345</id>
                    <name>LAPTOP1</name>
                    <failed_checks>
                        <check>
                            <checkid>9876543</checkid>
                            <check_type>687</check_type>
                            <description>Smart Error</description>
                            <startdate>2015-04-09</startdate>
                            <starttime>12:01:00</starttime>
                            <formatted_output>Smart Error</formatted_output>
                        </check>
                    </failed_checks>
                </workstation>
            </workstations>
        </site>
    </client>
    <client>
        <clientid>67543</clientid>
        <name>Contoso Ltd</name>
        <site>
            <siteid>98732</siteid>
            <name>Contoso Site A</name>
            <servers>
                <server>
                    <id>789999</id>
                    <name>SERVER1</name>
                    <failed_checks>
                        <check>
                            <checkid>76543555</checkid>
                            <check_type>2918</check_type>
                            <description>Disk Space Error - C:</description>
                            <startdate>2015-04-09</startdate>
                            <starttime>12:01:00</starttime>
                            <formatted_output>Total: 136.70GB, Free: 0.57GB</formatted_output>
                        </check>
                    </failed_checks>
                </server>
            </servers>
        </site>
    </client>       
</items>
```

All of my attempts have not completly fullfilled my needs.
I have no problem getting one value per `<client>`. I can retrive the `<client><name>` or i could get the value for `<check><description>` without trouble. My problem is when i want `<client><name>` togheter with `<workstation><name>` or `<server><name>` and the value for `<check><description>` and also `<check><startdate>`.

So in other words i would like to get this output;
Acme Inc LAPTOP1 Smart Error 2015-04-09
Contoso Ltd SERVER1 Disk Space Error - C: 2015-04-09

The best results i have got is with this code; (It's working but dont display correct - `<check><description>` dont match the `<client><name>`)
So my output is more like this now;
Acme Inc SERVER1 Disk Space Error - C: 2015-04-09
Contoso Ltd LAPTOP1 Smart Error 2015-04-09

```
Set xmlDOM = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmlDOM.async = False
xmlDOM.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
xmlDOM.Load("my xml file")

Set Root = xmlDOM.documentElement
Set NodeList = Root.getElementsByTagName("client")

For i = 0 to NodeList.length -1
  Set clientid = xmlDOM.getElementsByTagName("clientid")(i)
  Set name = xmlDOM.getElementsByTagName("name")(i)
  Set ckdesc = xmlDOM.getElementsByTagName("site/*/*/failed_checks/check/description")(i)
  Set ckdev = xmlDOM.getElementsByTagName("site/*/*/name")(i) 

  Response.Write clientid.text & " " & name.text & " " & ckdev.text & " " & ckdesc.text & "<br>"
Next

Set xmlDOM = Nothing
Set NodeList = Nothing
```

I've done some atempts with `selectNodes` and `selectSingleNode` that only display either the client name or check description. I have not managed to get the values togheter.

Comment: VMV, our suggested code worked like a charm! I didn't saw the whole thing until i saw the output from your working code.I'm adding an answer to VMVs answer instead of a writing the whole here to be able to easier show my code and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slint, i can't make all your jobs, sorry, but i think this algorithm will help you to solve problem:

```
Dim nodeListClient, nodeClient
Dim nodeListSite, nodeSite
Dim nodeListMachine, nodeMachine

' getting multiply <client> nodes
Set nodeListClient = xmlDom.selectNodes("/result/items/client")

' looping through collection
For Each nodeClient In nodeListClient

    ' getting multiply <site> nodes
    Set nodeListSite = nodeClient.selectNodes("./site")

    ' looping through collection    
    For Each nodeSite In nodeListSites

        ' getting multiply <workstation> or <server> nodes
        Set nodeListMachine = nodeSite.selectNodes("./*/*")

        ' looping through collection
        For Each nodeMachine In nodeListMachine
            ' there you will working with nodeMachine object
            ' nodeMachine contains <id>, <name> and other nodes
        Next
    Next

Next
```

I've recommend you to learn XPath documentation and examples, e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks VMV. You're absolutely right, you shouldn't do all the work. You gave a perfekt answer pointing me in the right direction, exactly what i wanted. OK, maybe it was a little more then just pointing in the right direction... Every thing is working in reciving the correct data. Now it's design and presentation thats needs a hands on.

Answer (score 1):

Use `selectNodes` and `selectSingleNode` like this:

```
Dim xmlDOM
Set xmlDOM = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmlDOM.LoadXml(sXml)

Dim NodeList, i, clientid, name, ckdesc, ckdev

Set NodeList = xmlDom.selectNodes("/result/items/client")

For i = 0 to NodeList.length -1
  Set clientid = NodeList(i).selectSingleNode("./clientid")
  Set name = NodeList(i).selectSingleNode("./name")
  Set ckdesc = NodeList(i).selectSingleNode("./site/*/*/failed_checks/check/description")
  Set ckdev = NodeList(i).selectSingleNode("./site/*/*/name")

  Response.Write clientid.text & " " & name.text & " " & ckdev.text & " " & ckdesc.text & "<br>"
Next

Set xmlDOM = Nothing
Set NodeList = Nothing
```

This code is not ideal, because before to get property value `clientid.text` and other you need to check that object exist (is not nothing), and many more error checks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an answer to VMVs answer to be able to easier show my code and output.

VMV, your suggested code worked like a charm! I didn't saw the whole thing until i saw the output from your working code. 
Problem now is that each `<client>` can have multiple `<sites>` and each `<site>` can have multiple `<workstations>`or `<servers>` with of course multiple `<check>`.

How can i do a loop in each `(i)`?

I've tried to do like the following code:
    Set NodeList = xmlDom.selectNodes("/result/items/client")

```
For i = 0 to NodeList.length -1
  Set clientid = NodeList(i).selectSingleNode("./clientid")
  Set name = NodeList(i).selectSingleNode("./name")

    Set NodeList2 = xmlDom.selectNodes("/result/items/client/site/*/*")
    For j = 0 to NodeList2.length -1
    Set ckdev = NodeList2(j).selectSingleNode("./name")     
        If Not ckdev Is Nothing Then    
            strckdev = strckdev & ckdev.text & " "
        Else
            strckdev = strckdev & "<br>"
        End If              

            Set NodeList3 = xmlDom.selectNodes("/result/items/client/site/*/*/failed_checks/check")
            For k = 0 to NodeList3.length -1
            Set ckdesc = NodeList3(k).selectSingleNode("./description")
              If Not ckdesc Is Nothing Then
                strckdesc = strckdesc & ckdesc.text & "<br>"
              Else
                strckdesc = strckdesc & "<br>"
              End If 
            Next      
    Next   

Response.Write clientid.text & " " & name.text & " " & strckdev & " " & strckdesc & "<br>"
Next
```

Now i get for each `<clientid>`every `<site>`. Not just the `<site>` for that specifik `<clientid>` (i).

The result is like this:

```
12345 Acme Inc LAPTOP1 SERVER1 Smart Error Disk Space Error - C:   
67543 Contoso Ltd LAPTOP1 SERVER1 Smart Error Disk Space Error - C:
```

I'm more looking for this result (if there where single or multiple computers with single or mutliple errors):

```
12345 Acme Inc 
      LAPTOP1 Smart Error 
      LAPTOP3 Some other error 
              Second error 

67543 Contoso Ltd
      SERVER1 Disk Space Error - C:
      Server7 Some other error
```

So my question, how do i loop in the loop..?

There are som obvious errors in my code where i Set NodeList2 and Set NodeList3 as that is going thru the XML file again and that's why i get the output wrong.

I also tried doing like this (Based on VMVs code);

```
Set clientid = NodeList(i).selectSingleNode("./clientid")
Set name = NodeList(i).selectSingleNode("./name")
Set ckdev = NodeList(i).selectNodes("./site/*/*/name") 
 For Each device In ckdev
   If Not device Is Nothing Then    
    strckdev = strckdev & device & " "
   Else
    strckdev = strckdev & "<br>"
   End If 
 Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on VMVs answers this is my working code. Data output in raw text without nice presentation.

```
Set xmlDOM = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmlDOM.async = False
xmlDOM.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
xmlDOM.Load("XMLfiletoload")

Dim nodeListClient, nodeClient
Dim nodeListSite, nodeSite
Dim nodeListMachine, nodeMachine
Dim nodeError, nodeErrorList

' getting multiply <client> nodes
Set nodeListClient = xmlDom.selectNodes("/result/items/client")

' looping through collection
For Each nodeClient In nodeListClient
  Set clientid = nodeClient.selectSingleNode("./clientid")
  Set name = nodeClient.selectSingleNode("./name")
    ' getting multiply <site> nodes
  strCLIENT = clientid.text & " " & name.text & "<br>"

    Set nodeListSite = nodeClient.selectNodes("./site")

    ' looping through collection    
    For Each nodeSite In nodeListSite
        Set cksite = nodeSite.selectSingleNode("./name")
        If Not cksite Is Nothing Then 
            strSITE = cksite.text & " "
        Else
            strSITE = " "
        End If

        ' getting multiply <workstation> or <server> nodes
        Set nodeListMachine = nodeSite.selectNodes("./*/*")

        ' looping through collection
        For Each nodeMachine In nodeListMachine
            ' there you will working with nodeMachine object
            ' nodeMachine contains <id>, <name> and other nodes

            Set ckdev = nodeMachine.selectSingleNode("./name")
            If Not ckdev Is Nothing Then 
                strONEDEVICE = ckdev.text & " "
            Else
                strONEDEVICE = ""
            End If  

            Set nodeErrorList = nodeMachine.selectNodes("./failed_checks/check")            
            ' looping through collection
            For Each nodeError In nodeErrorList
                    ' there you will working with nodeError object
                    ' nodeError contains <id>, <name> and other nodes

                Set ckdesc = nodeError.selectSingleNode("./description")
                If Not ckdesc Is Nothing Then 
                    strERROR = strERROR & ckdesc.text & "<br>"
                Else
                    strERROR = strERROR & "<br>"
                End If  

            Next
        strDEVICE = strDEVICE & strONEDEVICE & strERROR
        Next
        strSITE = strSITE & strDEVICE
    Next
              Response.Write strCLIENT & " " & strSITE & "<br>"
              strCLIENT = ""
              strSITE = ""
              strONEDEVICE = ""
              strDEVICE = ""
              strERROR = ""

Next
```